# pytest failing due to ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pytest, airflow

I am performing an integrity test on my Airflow DAGs using pytest, this is my current folder structure:

```
|-- dags
|   |-- 01_lasic_retraining_overview.py
|   |-- 02_lasic_retraining_sagemaker_autopilot.py
|   |-- 03_lasic_retraining_h20_automl.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- common
|       |-- __init__.py
|       `-- helper.py
|-- docker-compose.yaml
|-- newrelic.ini
|-- plugins
|-- requirements.txt
|-- sample.env
|-- setup.sh
|-- test.sh
`-- tests
    |-- common
    |   `-- test_helper.py
    `-- dags
        |-- test_02_lasic_retraining_sagemaker_autopilot.py
        |-- test_03_lasic_retraining_h20_automl.py
        `-- test_dag_integrity.py
```

In all my dags except `01_lasic_retraining_overview.py`(not testing), I import helper functions from `dags/common/helper.py` to them which is what is failing the test:

```
import airflow
    from airflow import DAG
    from airflow.exceptions import AirflowFailException
    from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
    from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook
>   from common.helper import _create_connection, _etl_lasic
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'

dags/03_lasic_retraining_h20_automl.py:6: ModuleNotFoundError
=================================== short test summary info ===================================
FAILED tests/dags/test_dag_integrity.py::test_dag_integrity[/Users/yravindranath/algo_lasic2_ct_pipeline/tests/dags/../../dags/02_lasic_retraining_sagemaker_autopilot.py]
FAILED tests/dags/test_dag_integrity.py::test_dag_integrity[/Users/yravindranath/algo_lasic2_ct_pipeline/tests/dags/../../dags/03_lasic_retraining_h20_automl.py]
```

Now this code runs with no issue in my docker container. Things that I have tried and did not work:

1. adding `__init__py` to the `tests` folder.
2. running `python -m pytest tests/`
3. removing the `__init__.py` files in the dir `dags`
4. setting `PYTHONPATH=. pytest`

##### Code for integrity test is at `/tests/dags/test_dag_integrity.py`

```
import re
import glob
import importlib.util
import os

import pytest
from airflow.models import DAG

# go to the root dir and browse for any files that match the pattern
# this will find all the dag files
DAG_PATH = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    "..",
    "..",
    "dags/**/0*.py",
)

# holds a list of all the dag files
DAG_FILES = glob.glob(
    DAG_PATH,
    recursive=True,
)
# filter the files to exclude the 01 dag run as that is just a plan of the
# pipeline
DAG_FILES = [file for file in DAG_FILES if not re.search("/01", file)]


@pytest.mark.parametrize("dag_file", DAG_FILES)
def test_dag_integrity(dag_file):
    # Load file
    module_name, _ = os.path.splitext(dag_file)
    module_path = os.path.join(DAG_PATH, dag_file)
    mod_spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(
        module_name,
        module_path,
    )
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(
        mod_spec,  # type: ignore
    )
    mod_spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
    # all objects of class DAG found in file
    dag_objects = [
        var
        for var in vars(module).values()
        if isinstance(
            var,
            DAG,
        )
    ]
    # check if DAG objects were found in the file
    assert dag_objects
    # check if there are no cycles in the dags
    for dag in dag_objects:
        dag.test_cycle()  # type: ignore
```

Comment: Try to work with relative import

Comment: @ozs like `from .common.helper import _create_connection, _etl_lasic`? It throws a similar error but different path now`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '/Users/yravindranath/algo_lasic2_ct_pipeline/tests/dags/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check what your `PYTHONPATH` is. You likely do not have `dags` in your `PYTHONPATH`. Likely your `PYTHONPATH` points to the root of your file structure, so the right way of importing the "common" folder of it is

```
import dags.common
```

Similarly as your common test code is

```
import tests.common
```

Python (even python 3) does not have a very good mechanism to import stuff relatively to the currently loaded file. Even if there are "relative" imports (with "." in front)  - they are confusing and work differently than you think they are. Avoid using them. Simply make sure your.

Also avoid setting PYTHONPATH to ".". It makes your import work differently depending on which is your current directory. Best way is to set it once and export.

```
export PYTHONPATH="$(pwd)"
```

The above will set the `PYTHONPATH` to the directory you are currently in and it will set it to absolute path.

Comment: Ah so the test run but now within the docker container I cannot import them `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dags'`, but that's another issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am also running the application in a Docker container where the answer provided by @Jarek Potiuk didn't work when actually running the DAG, so instead I am using a super hack way by just including the import parts that work in docker and the ones that work locally.

```
try:
    # Works locally with tests
    from common.helper import _create_connection, _etl_lasic
except ImportError:
    # Works in docker container
    from dags.common.helper import _create_connection, _etl_lasic
```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing a crazy idea here, try adding `__init__.py` both to `*/dag` or `*/common` and to `*/tests`.

Answer (score 0):

- Make `tests/conftest.py` file
- Create this fixture inside conftest.py

###### Make sure, your path name to the module `common` is correct

```
import pytest
import sys

@pytest.fixture(scope='session)
def append_path():
    sys.path.insert(0 , 'absolute_path_to_common_module' )
    yield
```

- Now use this fixture as :

> ```
> @pytest.mark.usefixtures("append_path") 
> @pytest.mark.parametrize("dag_file", DAG_FILES) 
> def test_dag_integrity(dag_file):
>     .....
> ```

What we are doing ?

- Making sure, the module is visible by python.

Note : You could rename your custom-module `common` to something less common and more unique. No pun intended.  To avoid any conflicts.